How to build calendar from rrule string with duration for every date using fullcalendar library?
I need to build a calendar from these 3 variables:

dtstart = '20240820T170000';
dtend = '20240820T190000';
rrule = 'FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20240917T235959Z;BYDAY=TU;WKST=SU';

So I write this code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.11.5/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.11.5/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrule@2.6.4/dist/es5/rrule.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/rrule@5.11.5/main.global.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            // Event details
            var dtstart = '20240820T170000';
            var dtend = '20240820T190000';
            var rrule = 'FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20240917T235959Z;BYDAY=TU;WKST=SU';

            // Function to calculate duration from DTSTART and DTEND
            function calculateDuration(dtstart, dtend) {
                var start = new Date(dtstart);
                var end = new Date(dtend);
                var durationInMs = end - start;
                var durationInHours = durationInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60);
                return durationInHours + ':00';
            }

            var duration = calculateDuration(dtstart, dtend);

            var calendarConfig = {
                firstDay: 1,
                headerToolbar: {
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                    center: 'title',
                    left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
                },
                initialDate: dtstart,
                events: []
            };

            var rruleString = 'DTSTART:' + dtstart + '\nRRULE:' + rrule;
            calendarConfig.events.push({
                title: '{{ view.field.title.original_value }}',
                rrule: rruleString,
                duration: duration // Use calculated duration
            });

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, calendarConfig);

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>

The calendar dates are detected correctly, but the times on those dates are not (look at the screenshots). Why?
Dates look good :

Times are not good :


This will be a timezone issue. It looks like rrule (or fullCalendar, I'm not completely sure) interprets your DTSTART as being in UTC, and then the calendar converts that to your local timezone to display it.

ok, i add timezone to code.
var calendarConfig = {
                firstDay: 1,
                headerToolbar: {
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                    center: 'title',
                    left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
                },
                initialDate: dtstart,
                events: [],
                timezone: 'Europe/Berlin'
};

Nothing changed.
